# Filming locations for Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home

Tags: star-trek, film-location

IMDB lists numerous filming locations for various scenes in Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home. Not explicitly listed are scenes set aboard the USS Enterprise (the aircraft carrier CVN 65). Of specific interest to me are the shots of Chekhov and Uhura at the nuclear reactor. In one shot there is a square-ish orange glass window, behind which are puffs of mist. That strikes me as a bit hokey, yet many of the aboard-ship scenes look plausibly like they were shot aboard a real naval vessel, especially what appears to be the hangar deck.

So... was the "reactor" real ship-board equipment, or a set on a sound stage? If real ship-board equipment, what was standing in for the reactor?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Memory Alpha, scenes for Star Trek IV were filmed on the USS Ranger (CV-61)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Ranger_(CV-61)) in two machinery rooms, an elevator, and the hanger bay. It doesn't elaborate on if the reactor scenes were filmed on the Ranger (if so, they would have been in a machinery room and not the ship's actual reactor) or on a sound stage. Watching the scenes, it seems like the reactor scenes were likely to have been filmed in a machinery room, but I can't find confirmation of the specific scenes shot on the Ranger.

Comment: USS Ranger was a conventional power ship.  Also, the marines chasing Chekov are actual US Marines actually chasing him.